# how to rename header in files in unix

Tags: unix

In unix, I have a bunch of files which id like to have the filename added to the header in the file, does anyone have a small script?

I have a bunch of files:

`abc.xxx
bac.xxx
cba.xxx`

within each file I have my data split, with a header for each section:

`*asdasd-123123
datadata`

`*asdasd-345345
datadata`

I'd like to have the filename added to the header in their respective files:

`*abc_asdasd-123123
datadata`

`*abc_asdasd-345345
datadata`

BR
Slyngej

Comment: `for f in *.xxx; do tag="$(echo "$f" | cut -c -3)"; sed "s/^\*/*${tag}_/" "$f" > "$f".mod; done`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ???.xxx   # grab file names in directory
do
        tag=`echo $f | cut -c -3`   # pick first 3 char to tag data
        sed "1s/^\*/*${tag}_/" $f > $f.mod  # modify first line, save it with .mod extention
done
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer. However, witin each file, there are several headers, and id like to have the file name added to all of them, not only the first line

Comment: a command "sed" is used for modify files.  Documentation is here:  https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html .  In the example, I used "1" for "Address" which is which line(s) sed should operate.  So you read section 4 of the documentation, and modify the command accordingly.  The "s" command is used, which is described in section 3.3.